# Compile Java project with Docker

Tags: java, docker

I am new to Docker. I have a problem with compiling the code with external library.

There is a ***lib*** folder (with the same level of "***src***" folder) that holding the library, such as abc.jar. I modified the Dockerfile as following. It compiled with no error but the project wasn't built with abc.jar.

```
# Compile our java files in this container
FROM openjdk:17-slim AS builder
COPY src /usr/src/project/src
COPY lib /usr/src/project/lib
COPY manifest.txt /usr/src/project/manifest.txt
WORKDIR /usr/src/project
RUN find . -name "*.java" | xargs javac -cp lib/abc.jar -d ./target
RUN jar cfm my_project.jar manifest.txt -C ./target/ .

# Copy the jar and test scenarios into our final image
FROM openjdk:17-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/project
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/project/my_project.jar ./my_project.jar
```

manifest.txt has

```
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: lib/abc.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "wasn't built with the abc.jar"?

Comment: I got ClassNotFound exception when I run the program when calling the class in abc.jar. Also, I use "jar -tf my_project.jar" to view the project structure, I don't see the lib/abc.jar within my project.

Comment: That isn't how Java works unless you explicitly create a fat jar (e.g., via Maven/Gradle).

Comment: You should copy abc.jar to target image and add it to classpath when running your jar.

Comment: Hi Sokolov, thanks for helping. Could you please elaborate more on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you use the library for compiling your project, you don't include it in the final image.
In multi-stage builds, each stage starts `FROM` a base image (`openjdk:17-slim` in this case) and unless you copy over the library, the final image will not include it.

This is how to do this:

```dockerfile
# Copy the jar and test scenarios into our final image
FROM openjdk:17-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/project
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/project/my_project.jar ./my_project.jar
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/project/lib/abc.jar ./lib/abc.jar
RUN java -jar my_project.jar
```

Comment: It works! Appreciate for your help Tasos.